# memset fuction does not work in my c++ dynamic array initialization

Tags: c++, arrays, opencv

This some parts of my opencv image processing codes.In it, I generate two dynamic arrays to store the total numbers of black points per col/row in binary image.
   Here are the codes:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Mat srcImg = imread("oura.bmp");
    width = srcImg.cols - 2;
    height = srcImg.rows - 2;

    Mat srcGrey;
    Mat srcRoi(srcImg, Rect(1, 1, width, height));
    cvtColor(srcRoi, srcGrey, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

    int thresh = 42;
    int maxval = 255;
    threshold(srcGrey, srcRoiBina, thresh, maxval, THRESH_BINARY);

    int *count_cols = new int[width] ();
    int *count_rows = new int[height] ();
    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
    {
        cout << count_cols[i] << endl;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        uchar *data = srcRoiBina.ptr<uchar>(i);
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            if (data[j] == 0)
            {
                count_cols[j]++;
                count_rows[i]++;
            }       
        }
    }

    delete[] count_cols;
    delete[] count_rows;
    return 0;
}
```

My question is that: if I use the follow codes

```
    int *count_cols = new int[width];
    int *count_rows = new int[height];
    memset(count_cols, 0, sizeof(count_cols));
    memset(count_rows, 0, sizeof(count_rows));
    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
    {
        cout << count_cols[i] << endl;
    }
```

to replace the corresponding codes below, why the dynamic arrays can not be initialized to zero? It seems that the memset does not work.

Platform: Visual Stdio 2013 + opencv 3.0.0

Could you please help me?

Additionally, the original image oura.bmp is 2592*1944.Thus the length of the dynamic array count_cols is 2590(ie, 2592-2). Is there some potential problems?

Comment: Very basic. The compiler doesn't know the size of a dynamically allocated memory block. `sizeof(count_cols)` is the size of the pointer itself, not the memory area it points to.

Comment: The length of the dynamic array count_cols is 2590(ie, 2592-2). Is there a limit for the length of dynamic array when using new? @Constantine Georgiou

Comment: The following two answers by Henning Koehler and cmannett85 are correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`count_cols` is of type `int*`, so `sizeof(count_cols)` will be 8 (64bit) or 4 (32bit). You'll want to use `sizeof(int) * width` instead (and similarly for rows).

Comment: The original image oura.bmp is 2592*1944.Thus the length of the dynamic array count_cols is 2590(ie, 2592-2). Is there some potential problems? Is there a limit for the length of dynamic array? @Henning Koehler

Comment: The limit for dynamic arrays is 2^64 bytes (on a 64 bit system) or (more likely) how much memory you have available. The issue is that the sizeof operator evaluates the size of your datatype, i.e. the pointer. It cannot tell you how much memory you have allocated at that address.
See also (http://c-faq.com/malloc/sizeof.html)

Comment: Thank you for your timely reply!

Answer (score 2):

`sizeof(count_rows)` is returning the size of the pointer, not the size of the array.

Use `height * sizeof(int)` instead.  Same applies for the columns too.

Comment: Could you please tell me some of your opinions about the question:  Is there a limit for the length of dynamic array?@cmannett85

Comment: @LittleTooth Henning's comment answered that question.

Comment: OK, I can see his answer now. Many thanks to you! @cmannett85